# Input text field with preset values

Tags: html

I have an input text field where the user is supposed to insert the time, one of the 24 hours. When the user starts to insert a number, a list of possible numbers should appear:

```
00:00
01:00
02:00
etc.
```

Would I need javascript for this or can this be done inherintly with html?

Comment: You could use a `<select>` if you want to stick with pure HTML (it'd work slightly differently though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML 5 introduced the [`datalist`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datalist.html) element with which you can achieve this. It would look like:

```
<datalist id="hour">
    <option value="00:00">
    <option value="01:00">
    <!-- ... -->
</datalist>

<input name="hour" list="hour" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aknQg/)

[However it is not supported in all browsers.](http://caniuse.com/datalist) It will only work in IE10 (buggy though), >FF4, >Chrome 20 and Opera. But not in Safari or older IE versions (don't even think about mobile browsers).

If you want a cross-browser solution, you have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cross browser solution, you will have to use some javascript.

I recommend you to look into [Chosen - JavaScript plugin for jQuery](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). It does exactly what you want, is cross browser, and has a slick interface.